# Phone thinks it is charging when not plugged in

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, hardware, charging

Quite often my phone lights up the charging symbol even if the phone isn't charging. It applies when it's of and on. The behaviour seems somewhat glitchy, it turns on and off.

Is this a well known error? Can I do something about it?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a damaged USB port.